# how to print the scalar value of the first different value

Tags: perl, scalar

The script below will print all the scalar value for every elements for every keys, how to print only the first scalar value from each element in the hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tie::IxHash;    

my %KEY_VALUE;
tie %KEY_VALUE,'Tie::IxHash';


my %KEY_VALUE= (
    0 => ['A','A','C','B','D'],
    1 => ['C','C','C','F','E','E'],
    2 => ['Z','X','X','A','A','Y','Y'],
    3 => ['A','A','B','B'],
    4 => ['E','E','R','M','M'],
    5 => ['D','F','F','F','E','E'],
    );

 while (my ($k, $v) = each %KEY_VALUE) 
{
  print "KEY= $k  ";
  print scalar "VALUE= @$v\n"; #But this will print all the value
}
```

Wanted Output:

```
KEY= 0  VALUE:0 2 3 4   #The scalar value of first A C B D, start with 0
KEY= 1  VALUE:0 3 4     #The scalar value of first C F E
KEY= 2  VALUE:0 1 3 5   #The scalar value of first Z X A Y
KEY= 3  VALUE:0 2       #The scalar value of first A B
KEY= 4  VALUE:0 2 3     #The scalar value of first E R M
KEY= 5  VALUE:0 1 4     #The scalar value of first D F E
```

Comment: You've shown a pattern of providing excessive information. Please post a *minimal* demonstration of the problem. The fact that you want to perform the operation on multiple arrays and that the arrays are referenced by a hash is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

```
my @vals = qw( Z X X A A Y Y );

my %seen;
my @positions = grep { !$seen{ $vals[$_] }++ } 0..$#vals;
```

This solution works even if identical strings haven't been grouped.

Comment: I don't know how to implement this code with the hash of arrays above.

Comment: Just replace `@vals` with the array you want to examine.

Comment: but for all arrays in a hash?

Comment: You mean for each array? You already have a loop that gives you each array

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
print scalar "VALUE= @$v\n"; #But this will print all the value
```

with

```
say "VALUE:0 ", join ' ', grep $v->[$_] ne $v->[$_ - 1], 1 .. $#$v;
```

- zero is always printed
- only show the indices for which the corresponding element is different to the previous one

This only works if the same letter never appears outside of the group of its first appearance (e.g. `A A B B A` doesn't happen). If this can happen, see ikegami's answer with a hash to keep track of the already reported letters.

Comment: Given their earlier question (about rearranging `Z X A Y X Y A` into `Z X X A A Y Y`), your assumption is probably valid.